# How To Change Font Size Based On Spinner Clicked

Tags: java, android, spinner

Before I explain to you, I told you, I've been searching in all of questions in stackoverflow and many webistes, so don't mark it duplicate or any negative acts. I've been stuck here more than 4 days.

I wanna change a font size based on spinner clicked. Every I click dropdown list spinner, it took me to java.lang.NullPointerException.  Here you go:

**MyAndroidAppActivity**

```
public class MyAndroidAppActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Spinner spinner1, spinnerLatin;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // toolbar
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    //this line shows back button
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    //Display data
    Spinner spinnerBackgroundChange = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spinnerArrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.country_arrays, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.textview_with_background);
    spinnerBackgroundChange.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

    addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();
    addListenerOnSpinner2ItemSelection();
}

public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new SelectedListener());
}

public void addListenerOnSpinner2ItemSelection() {
    spinnerLatin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerLatin);
    spinnerLatin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new SelectedLatin());
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            this.finish();
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
} }
```

**SelectedListener**

```
public class SelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

public void onItemSelected (AdapterView <?> parent, View view, int pos, long id){

    ((TextView) view).setTextColor(Color.RED);
    switch (pos) {
        case 0:
            TextView dgs = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sizedoa);
            dgs.setTextSize(30);
            break;
        case 1:
            TextView dgf = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fontLatin);
            dgf.setTextSize(30);
            break;
        default:
            //Default image
            //image.setImageResource(R.drawable.item2);
            break;

    }

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected (AdapterView <?> arg0){
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
} }
```

**main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/reldoa"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sizedoa"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="Ukuran Font"
                android:textColor="#222222"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/reldoa"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sizelatin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="Jenis Font"
        android:textColor="#222222"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:entries="@array/type_arrays"
        android:prompt="@string/type_font"/>

</RelativeLayout>

        <!-- Font latin -->

        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/relLatin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fontLatin"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:text="Font Latin"
                android:textColor="#226169"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

But, the problem lays here:
[Error located here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gn03r.png)

And this is the result of error:

```
10-05 00:20:08.848 5035-5035/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at id.or.tauhid.doadandzikir.SelectedListener.onItemSelected(SelectedListener.java:32)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:892)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.access$200(AdapterView.java:49)
    at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:860)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can you help me to fix the problem please? I've been stuck here 4 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your listener, these lines are almost certainly wrong:

> ```
> TextView dgs = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sizedoa);
> ```

> ```
> TextView dgf = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fontLatin);
> ```

The `view` argument passed to this method is the view *inside* the spinner that was clicked, which means that calling `view.findViewById()` will only look inside (a portion of) the spinner itself. Presumably these views are in your Fragment's or Activity's layout, and not inside the spinner.

How you fix this will depend on exactly how your app is wired together, but one potential possibility is to cast the `AdapterView`'s context to `Activity` and then find the views inside that:

```
Activity activity = (Activity) parent.getContext();
TextView dgs = activity.findViewById(R.id.sizedoa);
```

Comment: Big thanks Ben, your code working good. As we know together, that sizedoa and fontlatin located in main.xml, which is main.xml wired together with MyAndroidAppActivity and SelectedListener, this good. But the next problem is, when I try to connect to other xml file that has no relation with MyAndroidAppActivity and SelectedListener, it still show java.langNullPointerException. How do we fix the problem?

Comment: Can you help me to solve the next problem? when I try to connect to other xml file that has no relation with MyAndroidAppActivity and SelectedListener, it still show java.langNullPointerException